# Unable to install NodeJS 14 or 16 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS due to NO_PUBKEY not found error

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

My objective is to install NodeJS. This is the command I am running:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

It fails because of the following error:

```
W: GPG error: https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
```

Full stack trace is available appendix A.

I tried to resolve this key issue and ran following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
```

The result is some signatures not checked due to missing keys, full stack trace is available as Appendix B.

Then, when I try to update my system with the command, `sudo apt-get update`, I get the error: `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B`. Full stack trace is available as Appendix C.

How do I resolve gpg key error in order to install NodeJS14 or higher?

## Appendix A

```
root@vultr:~# curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Get:2 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease [1,468 B]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:2 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
E: The repository 'https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing the command, exiting
```

## Appendix B

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.bZCjA8xQN8/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
gpg: key FF0812D491B96798: 3 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key FF0812D491B96798: 8 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key FF0812D491B96798: "Parity Security Team <security@parity.io>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

## Appendix C

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Get:2 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease [1,468 B]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:2 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
E: The repository 'https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

## Update 1: Adding `-k` to `curl`:

```
root@vultr:~# curl -k -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

It did not change anything:

````
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease [1,468 B]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:1 https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
E: The repository 'https://releases.parity.io/deb release InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting```
````

Comment: I did not understand, can you verify whether we are on the same page by looking at my `Update 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently releases.parity.io/deb is unsigned or something. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository) answer suggests that you can add `[trusted=yes]` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` in order to avoid facing this error.

I couldn't advise on how secure that is.

EDIT:

Search for the line that starts with

```
deb https://releases.parity.io/deb
```

and change it to

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://releases.parity.io/deb
```

There are other alternatives mentioned in the linked answer that might also be worth checking out.

## Update 1: adding `[trusted=yes]` in the correct file

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parity.list` has the line:
`deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/parity.gpg] https://releases.parity.io/deb release main`.
This line should be modified to make it work:
`deb [trusted=yes,signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/parity.gpg] https://releases.parity.io/deb release main`

Comment: So, what do I add in the file? Can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava it is explained in the linked answer but I added it here as well.

Comment: Yes, but the linked answer has two more entries in the same line, `jesse` and `main`. I don't know what to enter in my file and if I don't add anything, it results in syntax error.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava you should already have this line, you don't need to add a new entry, just look for it.

Comment: I don't have any line where this can be added. There was no line with `parity` mentioned.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava hm, that's weird, why is it being picked up when an update is issued then? I'm not that experienced to tell what's going on but the next answer suggests adding `--allow-unauthenticated` to `apt update`. Try it manually and see if that works - if it does then modify the nodejs install script and add it there.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I just did a quick research, there's also the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory where you'll find more files, perhaps it resides in one of them.

Comment: I don't think that skipping the package signature altogether is the answer ...that's alike accepting that the system is fundamentally broken ...and pretending that nothing ever happened.

Comment: This answer worked after I edited the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parity.list` by adding `[trusted=yes]` to make it: `deb [trusted=yes,signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/parity.gpg] https://releases.parity.io/deb release main`.

Thanks @php_nub_qq for helping out.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava happy to help, as others and myself mentioned, it is probably not a very good idea to do this if it is some kind of production environment. But I suspect that it is not the case and you will probably be fine.

Comment: The current node instructions now specify a sources list named "nodesource.list", with nodesource.gpg as the key file.  I tried these instructions on that line but it had no effect...

Answer (score 1):

Likely a GPG keyring at `/usr/share/keyrings/` had been corrupted - that's why no key matches anymore. You could create a new keyring and start adding back the keys with `apt-key --keyring`.

Maybe try requesting through port `:80` (no clue why this works):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3B1FE9FFD0787F8B
```